# web.py script keeps saying, "'return' outside function"

Tags: python, error-handling, web.py

Whenever I try to run this script with web.py I get the error message

```
<type 'exceptions.SyntaxError'> at /hello
'return' outside function (app.py, line 19)
```

Here is my source:

```
import web
urls = (
'/hello', 'Index',
'/file_upload_form', 'ThatFile'
)

app = web.application(urls, globals())

render = web.template.render('templates/', base = "layout")

class ThatFile(object):
    def GET(self):
        return render.file_upload_form()

    def POST(self):
        form = web.input(image = "loc")
        image_o = open(form.image,'r')
        return render.thatfile(image_o = image_o)

class Index(object):

    def GET(self):
        return render.hello_form()

    def POST(self):
        form = web.input(name = "Nobody", greet = None)
        greeting = "%s, %s" % (form.greet, form.name)
        return render.index(greeting = greeting)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I've tried re-indenting the 'returns' but I just get that message.

Comment: check tab/spaces issues by visualising whitespace or Python/Scripts/tabnanny.py

Answer (score 3):

Your code has mixed tabs and spaces, which is confusing Python. You can choose to use tabs, or you can choose to use spaces ([PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends spaces), but you **must** be consistent.

Check your editor settings to see whether you can tell it to show you tabs and spaces differently (most editors can do this).